# Browser cannot do remote request to a server that does not support CORS

Tags: javascript, debugging, xmlhttprequest, cors, fiddler

I'm developing an web application that needs to access a remote server through JSON from the browser, but the remote server does not support CORS.  The server will eventually support CORS.  But I need the browser to access the remote server during my development and testing phase.

How can I get the browser to allow responses from servers that do not have CORS enabled?

Newer browsers have security limitation for Cross-Origin resource sharing (CORS).  For these browsers, if the response header from the servers do not contain “Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *” then the browser may raise an error such as: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I hope this answer will be helpful to anyone looking for a cheap, temporary patch to avoid CORS policy.

If you are using Google Chrome, there is a command line option wich you can disable CORS restriction with.
Simply create a new plain text file and put this inside:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

Just save this file as **something.bat** in Windows to ease its use. Or you can use the modifiers directly in terminal (works for both windows/unix environment).

**Important sidenote**:
This is just a cheap, fast and dirty workaround JUST for developing environments. Please do not consider this possibility for production environments nor users.
The best way to fix CORS is by really fixing CORS headers on server-side.

Answer (score 3):

There may be situations in testing and debugging where you want to allow CORS but don’t have the ability to change the server to allow CORS.  There are a few options to solve this.  Here I'm going to discussing solving this problem by using Fiddler.

By using Fiddler I can see the results that should be returned from a server that supports CORS. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*".
[image]

But the problem that is occurring is that the remote server is not returning "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" in the response headers.

To solve this we can instruct Fiddler to add the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" to all response.

To do this open Fiddler Customize Rules (see image).

[image]

Add the following code in the code section OnBeforeResponse

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
   if(!oSession.oResponse.headers.Exists("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
   {
        oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   }
```

Now your browser should have the ability to access servers that do not support CORS.  One problem with this solution is that you must have Fiddler running.

Comment: You have a good point.  I know I got it to work with with IE9, but had couldn't do CORS with a remote server that didn't have it enabled.  I will need to research that more.  For the time being I will remove that comment from the answer.

Comment: Older browsers don't support CORS and you'd need to use JSONP or a similar approach. For IE8/IE9 only, you can use `XDomainRequest`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem.. so added an intermediate server and made that server communicate to cors unsupported server. as cors is blocked by only browser now I am doing this call from the intermediate sever and bypassing the problem.

https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/c2fd954f377a895473c5

[image]

The idea is this:
 if the server you are communicating to does not support cors, bring in an intermediate server that supports cors and make the call to the cors-unsupported server from the intermediate server .
It works like a charm for me.

In that script 
https://cors-unsupported-server - cors unsupported server
the script interimserver.py - cors supported intermediate server

you have to call localhost:5000/orc and submit request(note: the script only has post if you want others just change that httpmethod to the desired one) .
the interimserver will forward it to the cors unsupported server and get the reply and forwards it back to you.

***Moral of the story :***

only browser side script needs to obey rules(because broswer imposes rules in the form of doing some additional things like setting HOST  header. (this HOST header is the one that tell the server where the request came from. if you can change this host to the host of the cors-unsupported server , that too will work .[how to confirm ? set the HOST header in my script to domain other than the cors-unsupported server and you see that the script even fails. now set it to cors-unsupported server and you will find it working.]).

my server side script will not obey browser rules. I will do anything .